# List not displaying in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am attempting to display a listview in a fragment. However, nothing is displaying and the logging seems correct. The screen is completely blank. I thought the cause was an error in inflating the view, but I just have no clue. I have researched SO and other websites with no luck.

```
     @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.v("FeaturesFragment", "FeaturesFragment");

        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carfeatures_list, container, false);
        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.features_list_item, container, false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.features_list_item, null);
        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carfeatures_list,null);
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Log.v("ListView lv1-features", lv.toString());

        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(carFeaturesList, R.layout.carfeatures_list, super.getActivity());
        //adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(carFeaturesList, R.layout.features_list_item, super.getActivity());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.v("ListView lv2-features", lv.toString());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Gets values from selected ListItem

                String car_features = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_features)).getText().toString();
                //Log.v("onCreate-car_features", car_features.toString());

                String carfeatures_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_id)).getText().toString();
                //Log.v("onCreate-carfeatures_id", carfeatures_id.toString());

                String model_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_id)).getText().toString();
                //Log.v("onCreate-model_id", model_id.toString());

                String carfeatures_desc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_desc)).getText().toString();
                //Log.v("onCreate-carfeats_desc", carfeatures_desc.toString());

                Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(TAG_CARID);
                if (b == true) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

                //Colors the selected listview item
                if (previouslySelectedItem != null) {
                    previouslySelectedItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    //Log.v("previouslySelectedItem", "!=null");
                    //Log.v("position", Integer.toString(position));
                }

                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                //Log.v("position", Integer.toString(position));
                //Log.v("outofif-view", view.toString());
                previouslySelectedItem = view;
            }
        });

        //Calls async task to get json
        new GetCarFeatures().execute();

        Log.v("return called-Features", "return called");
        Log.v("v", v.toString());
        return v;
    }

@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            CarFeatures item = getItem(position);
            //Log.v("CarFeaturesitem", Integer.toString(position));

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.carfeatures_list, null);
                //convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.features_list_item, null);
                Log.v("getView", "getView");
                Log.v("View convertView", convertView.toString());
                Log.v("ViewGroup parent", parent.toString());

                holder.carfeatures_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_id);
                //Log.v("if-holder.carfeat_id", holder.carfeatures_id.toString());

                holder.model_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.model_id);
                //Log.v("if-holder.model_id", holder.model_id.toString());

                holder.carfeatures_desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.carfeatures_desc);
                //Log.v("if-holder.carfeat_id", holder.carfeatures_desc.toString());

                convertView.setTag(holder);
                //Log.v("if-convertView", convertView.toString());
                //Log.v("if-holder", holder.toString());

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                //Log.v("else-convertView", convertView.toString());
                //Log.v("else-holder", holder.toString());
            }

            holder.carfeatures_id.setText(item.carfeatures);
            //Log.v("holder.carfeatures_id", holder.carfeatures_id.toString());

            holder.model_id.setText(item.modelid);
            //Log.v("holder.model_id", holder.model_id.toString());

            holder.carfeatures_desc.setText(item.carfeaturesdesc);
            //Log.v("holder.carfeatures_desc", holder.carfeatures_desc.toString());

            adapter.getItemId(position);
            //Log.v("getitemid1", Long.toString(adapter.getItemId(position)));

            Log.v("convertView", convertView.toString());
            return convertView;

        }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/car_features"
        android:layout_below="@+id/model_id"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/carfeatures_id"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/car_features" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/model_id"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/carfeatures_desc"
        android:layout_above="@+id/car_features"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML may be misconfigured. For example, you have `android:layout_below="@+id/header` and there is no header ID here. You also don't need a plus on any ids you aren't adding.

Comment: Relating future questions: Could you try to show only relevant code? It's hard to figure out, what line exactly is the problem, but in many cases you can break it down to a few lines of code. If you just copy so much code, only a few people will read your question completly and you will get less answers.

Comment: First of all your ListView has a match_parent height and the parent layout (RelativeLayout) has a wrap_content height, you could at least set the height of the relative view to match parent if is the root of your activity/fragment and if the fragment is set on a view that has match parent as a height

Comment: To eliminate ambiguity you should update your question and note the given XML layout so we can know if that represents the layout inflated in the fragment or in the adapter :)

Comment: @Cata Updated. The layout that is inflated is noted.

Comment: How do you set the fragment on your activity? Is onCreateView get called?

Comment: The fragment is called from MainActivity on a RadioButton click. onCreateView is called.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you set the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems that in your

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

you are trying to inflate this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/car_features"
            android:layout_below="@+id/model_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/carfeatures_id"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/car_features" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/model_id"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/carfeatures_desc"
            android:layout_above="@+id/car_features"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

which will not work, because you need to inflate an **item** of the list (not the layout containig the list), an item, which you will fill with your data from array. I would suggest you to create a layout for that item, name it `list_item.xml` and inflate it.

Oh, and in case you have this item, please show it to us

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are explaining, please? I am confused.

Comment: RexSplode is right, you should not inflate that layout in your ListView adapter. You should instead have a different layout for your listview items..

Comment: So have one layout file that only contains the listview? And then have another layout file that only contains the textviews? Would I inflate the textviews in getView and then inflate the listview in oncreateview?

Comment: Yep, that should be :)

Comment: @Cata Please see my updated post. I did exactly what I questioned. I have two layout files- features_list_item only has the listview which is implemented in oncreateview and carfeatures_list only has textviews which is implemented in the adapter and getview. I still have a blank screen.

Comment: Now you changed the code and your adapter method appeared in your Activity. You need to have the layout containing your listview. That layout you inflate in your activity. Aaand you need to have an adapter class, which inflates 'list_item' in 'getView()'. Also make sure you pass 'R.layout.list_item ' to Adapter;s constructor, **not list.xml!**